# How to delete a file in file handling in c++

Tags: c++

i made a function that first reads the file and checks if it exists or not and then it removes it after a confirmation but if i do directly like

```
remove("a.text");
```

it deletes the file that has the name a.txt but when i use my function

```
int deletediary()
{
    string searchfilename;
    cout<<"\nPlease enter the filename to be searched\n";
    cin>>searchfilename;
    searchfilename.append(".txt");
    fileread.open(searchfilename.c_str());
    if(!fileread){
        cout<<"\nERROR :Either you didn't enter an invalid date or you entered an date with no entry\n\n";
        A :
        cout<<"Continue to search? (y/n)\n";
        if(getch()=='y')
        {
            modifydiary();
        }
        else if(getch()=='n')
        {
            menuview();
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<"Enter Correct Option\n";
            goto A;
        }
    }
    else{
        system("cls");
        int i;
        B :
        cout<<"Are you sure you want to remove this diary entry? (y/n)";
        if(getch()=='y')
        {
            remove(searchfilename.c_str());
        }
        else if(getch()=='n')
        {
            menuview();
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<"Enter Correct Option\n";
            goto B;
        }   
        cout<<"INFO :Deleted!!!";
        system("pause");
        menuview();
    }
```

it only checks the filename but does not delete it.

Comment: avoid goto and use std::filesystem

Comment: but how is my using goto related to the remove() function?

Comment: it's not, that's why I wrote a comment only.

Comment: You forgot to close the file before deleting. Do that and it should work

Comment: thanks, it really did the trick @TheApache

Comment: @AkhileshSharma so, can you please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: oops , i am sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot closing the file that you have opened. 
So, **CLOSE the file and it should work.**

Note: The solution worked for @AkhileshSharma and included the comment as an answer to close the question as answered.

Answer (score 27):

In `c++17` we have the [filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) library, which gives the tools to easily deal with the problem.

Example:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string searchfilename;
  std::cout << "Please enter the filename to be searched\n";
  std::cin >> searchfilename;
  try {
    if (std::filesystem::remove(searchfilename))
       std::cout << "file " << searchfilename << " deleted.\n";
    else
       std::cout << "file " << searchfilename << " not found.\n";
  }
  catch(const std::filesystem::filesystem_error& err) {
     std::cout << "filesystem error: " << err.what() << '\n';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When you try to delete a file, you should always handle the return value of **remove** function immediately. For successful result it returns `0` and for failed, it returns non-zero.

```
const int result = remove( "no-file" );
if( result == 0 ){
    printf( "success\n" );
} else {
    printf( "%s\n", strerror( errno ) ); // No such file or directory
}
```

`remove` is in the `stdio.h` file
and `strerror` is in the `string.h`

So after your `remove` function, check to see for what reason it has not been deleted.
The error number is stored in `errno` variable and `strerror` can map the error number to a string that tells the reason of failure.

---

Also you can test the error code and a Linux Terminal if you have it using `perror` command

```
> perror 0
OS error code   0:  Success
> perror 1
OS error code   1:  Operation not permitted
> perror 2
OS error code   2:  No such file or directory
> perror 3
OS error code   3:  No such process
> perror 4
OS error code   4:  Interrupted system call
> perror 5
OS error code   5:  Input/output error
```

Comment: yes i added stdio in my code earlier but still it didn't work but as @TheApache said, i had not closed the file before remove() so i guess, that was the real problem

Comment: This is the single correct answer (the one given by The Apache is correct insofar as it works around the issue, too, but it doesn't address the issue). People tend to never check return values. Close a socket? Who cares about the return value. Delete a file? Who cares. This stuff is important. If you don't check return values, your program is broken. If anything goes the irregular way, you have no way of knowing, the program just fails _silently_.

Answer (score 0):

here's another simple way to delete a file

```
//complete location of file with path
std::string fileLocStr;
fileLocStr.append("C:\temp\test.txt");

//create dos command to delete file
std::string delFileCmd = "del /s /q " + fileLocStr;
cout << "delFileCmd: " << delFileCmd << endl;

//this executes the command
int delFileStatus = system(delFileCmd.c_str());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//you have to give the path of the file for example(path="C:\\data\\newfolder")
       System::IO::DirectoryInfo^  directory = gcnew System::IO::DirectoryInfo(path);
       for each(System::IO::FileInfo^ file in directory->GetFiles())
       {
       //for getting the extension of file(if you want to delete specific extension file)
       String^ s = file->Extension;
       if (file->Extension == ".png")
       {
        file->Delete();
       }
       }
```

Comment: This appears to be C#, not C++